# NHibernate generated GUID - field type

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate

I'm new to NHibernate.
If I use NHibernate to generate GUIDs for inserts to MS Sql2005, what type does the id field in the db need to be.
Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I edited my answer to be a link to the MSDN for the data type, and the accepted answer dropped off. Not complaining if so, just wanted to know if you actively un-flagged it, or if was a bug related to the edit. thx.

Comment: I unflagged it by mistake. Sorry. 
Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[uniqueidentifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190215(SQL.90).aspx)